# Why does authorize directive execute after the code it's supposed to protect?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am using Scala 2.11.2, Akka 2.3.6 and Spray 1.3.2.

I'm facing an issue with the `authorize` directive. Here is the interesting part of the code:

```
val authenticatorActor = context.actorOf(Props[AuthenticatorActor])
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

cookie("userName") { cookie =>
  def optionUser = Await.result(authenticatorActor ? cookie.content, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Option[User]]
  authorize(isAuthorized(optionUser)) { // ?????
    val user = optionUser.get
    //do stuff
  }
}

def isAuthorized(user: Option[User]): Boolean = 
  user match {
    case Some[User] => true
    case None       => false
  }
```

Basically, I check the cookie to validate the user credentials.

The problem is that the block inside the `authorize` directive is executed before the `isAuthorize` method.

So if the future returns a `None`, code fails in `val user = optionUser.get` with an ugly `NonSuchElementException`.

If the `authorize` directive is changed by an `if` statement like in the snippet below all work fine:

```
if (isAuthorized(optionUser)) {
  //do stuff 
} else reject(ValidationRejection("User has not access"))
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I'm adding the `//do stuff` block for reference

```
get {
  path("") {
    complete {
      s"Hi ${user.name}. You have the next access: ${user.acceso}.\nWelcome to the ping-pong match" 
    }
  } ~
  path("ping") {
    complete("pong")
  } ~
  path("pong") {
    complete ("ping")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `//do stuff` code in a `complete` block?  [This might be happening](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions). It's something I've had to relearn multiple times.

Comment: thanks for the answer Gangstead. I add to the question the content in the //do stuff, is not much longer. It contains a get/path() hierarchy with a complete block at the end. I think this should be ok. By the way, +1 because of the link to the documentation, I always forget it too

Comment: This is working for me with some minor fixes (e.g. the pattern match in `isAuthorized`, which actually doesn't compile). Can you also post the exception you mentioned as well as the `AuthenticatorActor`? Which spray version are your using?

Comment: Ouch, sorry guys, I forgot to add the problematic line. Just added to the question and added version information too. The error is here: `val user = optionUser.get` so when the optionUser value is None it shoots a NonSuchElementException.

Comment: Then @Gangstead is right. Your `optionUser.get` line isn't in a `complete` block, thus the respective code is run when the route is being built.

Comment: Ok, both are right. If you put the ´optionUser.get´ into the complete block works ok. But I still don´t understand why this statement is executed before the authorize directive. is there a link somewhere with information? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gangstead and user3567830 for the answere.

As states in the docs

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions

The correct way is like this:

```
authorize(isAuthorize(optionUser)) {
        get {
          path("") {
            complete {
              val user = optionUser.get
              s"Hi ${user.name}. You have the next access: ${user.acceso}.\nWellcome to the ping-pong match"
            }
          }
       }
            ....
```